# Active Directory - Filling in unique ID by script

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2008-r2

I want to fill in the "employeeID" or "uid" of our users in Active Directory with a sequential number. Only thing that I made is exporting the user in a CSV file:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "mail -like '*com'" | Export-Csv 'C:\ADUser.csv' -NoType
```

Has anyone an idea how I can do anything like this?

Comment: The employee id is not mandated by HR? What's the use then?

Comment: HR employee id's are in another application - thats our problem. I set up an LDS and synchronized all users to the LDS instance. So I need to fill in any attribute (employeeID, uid or another self created attribute) with an unique ID, which is needed for our WSO2 Identity Server.

Comment: I'd look at the application that currently holds the 'HR' employee id and see if it can be setup to synchronise this to AD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sets all the users EmployeeID fields to a number sequentially starting from 1:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "mail -like '*com'" | ForEach-Object -Begin {$UserID = 1} {
    Set-ADUser $_ -EmployeeID $UserID -WhatIf
    $UserID++
}
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` parameter if it looks to be doing what you desired. Beware that it will likely replace any existing value for all these users and it doesn't account for the possiblity that other user objects in the domain might have the same ID (as you've filtered to users with an email address).

If you want a CSV output at the end with the results you could further do this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "mail -like '*com'" | ForEach-Object -Begin {$UserID = 1} {
    Set-ADUser $_ -EmployeeID $UserID -WhatIf
    $UserID++

    Get-ADUser $_ -Properties Samaccountname,EmployeeID | Select Samaccountname,EmployeeID        
} | Export-Csv 'C:\ADUser.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: This looks helpful, i will check. Thank you.

Comment: This is the which I get for this:

_Set-ADUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '1++'.
At line:1 char:90
+ Get-ADUser -Filter "mail -like '*com'" | ForEach-Object -Begin {$UserID = 1} { Set-ADUser <<<<  $_ -employeeID $UserID -WhatIf $UserID++ }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser_

Comment: It looks like you're putting `$UserID++` on the end of the `Set-ADUser` line, rather than on a new line.

Comment: I had many backspaces after the "-WhatIf", that was the problem. The next report ist: _What if: Performing operation "Set" on Target "CN=..._ 

And without the "-WhatIf": I don't get any errors or reports, but it happens nothing.

Comment: Does anything get written to the CSV?

Comment: No, it's empty.

Comment: If you run this part on its own, do you get results? `Get-ADUser -Filter "mail -like '*com'"`

Comment: I get a list of users.

Comment: Ok, it worked or works. The problem was, I ran the script on our AD LDS machine, but the script changed the attributes on the AD. Is it possible to use self created attributes insted of "employeeID"?

Comment: Yeah I think so, you just need to name them in the -properties parameter. Oh although I'm not sure how you handle that with the set command. Try reading the help page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts and help.